# Unable to access api endpoint. Cloud foundry installed from cf_nise

Tags: vagrant, cloud-foundry

I have installed a local cloud foundry instance following [cf_nise_installer](https://github.com/yudai/cf_nise_installer)

**Environment:**

```
Host: Windows 10
Vagrant: 1.7.4
Virtualbox: 5.0.2
cf: 6.13.0-e68ce0f-2015-10-15T15:53:50+00:00
```

Installation went fine but when I try to access the endpoint using the command:

```
cf login -a https://api.10.0.2.15.xip.io -u admin -p c1oudc0w --skip-ssl-validation
```

I get following error

```
API endpoint: https://api.10.0.2.15.xip.io
FAILED 
Error performing request: Get https://api.10.0.2.15.xip.io/v2/info: dial tcp
10.0.2.15:443: ConnectEx tcp: i/o timeout
```

I googled and found it be some DNS and /etc/hosts entries issue so I changed the DNS of my wifi adapter to 8.8.8.8 / 8.8.4.4 and added following entries to the /etc/hosts file

```
10.0.2.15 api.10.0.2.15.xip.io
10.0.2.15 uaa.10.0.2.15.xip.io
10.0.2.15 10.0.2.15.xip.io
10.0.2.15 hello.10.0.2.15.xip.io
```

I flushed the DNS, restarted but still I am getting same error.

Below is the output of **nslookup api.10.0.2.15.xip.io**

```
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    api.10.0.2.15.xip.io
Address:  10.0.2.15
```

Now I am out of options. Please guide me what I am missing.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you expect `https://api.10.0.2.15.xip.io` to work, i.e., why `10.0.2.15`?  Why not `10.39.39.39` which appears to be the [`NISE_IP_ADDRESS`](https://github.com/yudai/cf_nise_installer/blob/master/Vagrantfile#L3) or `192.168.10.10` which appears to be the address used by all the internal components and addresses, including the [`system_domain`](https://github.com/yudai/cf_nise_installer/blob/master/manifests/template.yml#L32)?

Comment: This is what I get once I run ./scripts/start.sh. I'll try 10.39.39.39

Comment: I doubt 10.39.39.39 will work (doesn't hurt to try), I was just unsure why 10.0.2.15 was supposed to work.

Comment: It doesn't work.
Server error, status code: 404, error code: 0, message:

Comment: nor does 192.168.10.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to resolve this by adding route to the 10.0.2.15

In my routing table, there was no entry for the above IP so I added an entry as 
**route add 10.0.2.15 10.39.39.1** where 10.39.39.1 is the IP of virtual box host only adapter.

This resolved the issue.